Amplify Gen2 Push notifications (Swift)
I want to send push notifications to my iOS app with Amplify Gen 2.
Gen1 document does exist: https://docs.amplify.aws/gen1/swift/build-a-backend/push-notifications/set-up-push-notifications/
But, I did not find a document for Gen 2.
Does gen 2 support Push Notification feature?
